# Adding random variables in definition of sample mean

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

When I add two random variables, are they added pointwise on $\Omega$, as in $X+Y(\omega):=X(\omega)+Y(\omega)$ or are they added $X+Y(\omega_1,\omega_2)=X(\omega_1)+Y(\omega_2)$ on $\Omega \times \Omega$? Going one step further, would it be correct to define the sample mean as  as $\overline{X}(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n)=\frac{X_1(\omega_1)+\dots +X_n(\omega_n)}{n}$ over $\Omega \times \dots \times \Omega$ for $X_1\dots X_n$ iid? Many stats definitions write this as

$$\overline{X} = \frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{n}$$  which makes it unclear as to what the domainn is and I thought for the longest time the domain was simply $\Omega$.

Comment: The domain is $\Omega$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Then wouldnt this mean that $\overline X (\omega)= \frac{nX_1(\omega)}{n}$? All of these random variables would have to map to the same value since they are iid and are getting the same input. This does not make sense to me at all

Comment: $X_i$'s being i.i.d. does not mean $X_1(\omega)=X_2(\omega)$ etc.

Comment: @geetha290krm They just have the same distribution? But suppose the sample space is all people and the r.v. maps to heights. Certainly then all the $X_1,X_2,\dots X_n$ must be the same. In which case how would you sample from this? Every r.v. would map a person to the same height

Comment: Your example does not define $\Omega$ or $X_i(\omega)$, so it cannot be objectively understood and there is no way of claiming $X_1=X_2$.

Comment: One example of two i.i.d. random variables $X$ and $Y$ is if I roll a 4-sided die with equally likely outcomes $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and define Bernoulli variables $X(\omega)=1_{\{\omega \in \{1,3\}\}}$ and $Y(\omega)=1_{\{\omega \in \{1,2\}\}}$, where $1_A$ is an indicator function that is 1 if event $A$ is true, and 0 else.  You can check, for example,  $P[X=1, Y=1]=P[X=1]P[Y=1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is abstracted away. The answer to your question is that it depends on what the sample space $\Omega$ is. Real-valued random variables living on the same probability space, say $X$ or $Y$, are simply maps from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The outcomes $\omega$ in the sample space $\Omega$ are often not explicitly referred to, as long as $\Omega$ is rich enough to accommodate the desired amount of randomness.

If you had two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, a canonical construction of the sample space is a product space: i.e. the sample points consist of tuples $\omega = (\omega_1, \omega_2)$, where each coordinate supports a particular random variable. If you had $n$ independent random variables, you could do the same thing: $\omega = (\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots, \omega_n)$. Now more generally, you could allow for a sequence of random variables with sample points $\omega = (\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots)$.

Typically, this last setting is the probability space working under the setting where you have a sequence of random variables, such as the sample mean you are asking about. In this case, we still only have the one probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, so $\overline{X}_n$ is still a map from $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.